# Trying to get eclipse projects to import after transferring everything to new laptop

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I got a new laptop and copied all my eclipse stuff from my old laptop to new one.

It was actually the same laptop model just upgraded a few things (mem, drive size, etc)

So the drive letters are the same as the old laptop.

When i originally opened eclipse i got an error message and read on this site to delete the "org.eclipse.core.resources" folder in .metedata/.plugins folder.

So that go eclipse to open.

After opening i dont see any of my projects even though the workspace is already set correctly.

So i tried importing android project and eclipse project but i get errors saying the packages are already there. even though i dont see them in the project explorer.

Whats the easiest way to get my projects back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your  projects on your workspace again, you can go on `File` -> `Import`. It will open a modal, then you select `General` -> `Existing Projects In Workspace`. Now just select your root directory and it will list all of your projects to be imported.

One important thing is that this method does not import things like Working Sets. If you had your workspace customized, it won't bring any of these customizations back. Still, it is better have your projects back than nothing.

EDIT:

As it didn't work, you also can delete the `.metadata` folder and it will be like you never had this workspace. After that, you can try to import the projects again.

Comment: I tried that. Here is the error i get https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5012364/Untitled%20picture%20%2843%29.png

Comment: If you don't care about the customizations I said, just delete the `.metadata` folder. If you are afraid of doing it, just move it to another folder and try to import the projects again.

Comment: As you can see my projects workspace is empty https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5012364/Untitled%20picture%20%2844%29.png